# removing special characters in asp

Tags: asp-classic, character-encoding

I want to identify special characters and remove that special characters from my string or a word

for example

1. O'neil - i want to remove (') from this word.
2. Muñoz, A. Patrick - i want to remove above character of n (ñ)

similarly i want to remove all special characters from my strings.

I want to do this in asp

How can i do this

Comment: Are you using ASP, or ASP.NET? C#/VB.Net ?

Comment: Asp, please give me code in asp only

Comment: The ' character indicates to me that sql security may be driving this. If so, you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression and then run the following. You'll need to change the regular expression accordingly.

```
Const PATTERN = "\W"
Dim objRegEx
Dim strReplacedString : strReplacedString = ""
Set objRegEx= New RegExp 
objRegEx.Pattern = PATTERN 
objRegEx.IgnoreCase = True 
objRegEx.Global = True 
strReplacedString = objRegEx.Replace(strToProcess,"")
Set objRegEx = Nothing
```